# Get number from call log when contact is created

Tags: android, contacts, calllog

I have created a alternative app for creating a new contact in android. It works fine when we create a contact.

But when we create a contact from call log selecting "create contact" in context menu, I have not being able to get phone number that was selected to create contact.

Plz help me...

Comment: are you using ACTION_INSERT intent filter?

Comment: Yes. i am using ACTION_INSERT intent filter.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit Late but this works for me.

Add this in your android manif
`

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="Edit/Add Property/Requirement">
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
              <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/person" android:host="contacts" />
              <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/contact" android:host="com.android.contacts" />
              <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/raw_contact" android:host="com.android.contacts" />
          </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="Add Property/Requirement">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/person" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/raw_contact" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>`
```

This activity will be the one to create contact. And inside the activity, use this code to capture the phone number

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    try{
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        if (uri.toString().endsWith("contacts")) // new contact
        {
            phoneNumber = intent
                    .getStringExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE);
        }
        else{
            ContactID = ""+ContentUris.parseId(uri);
            phoneNumber = intent
                    .getStringExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception E){

    }
```

Hope this helps :)